# How to call ActivityGroup method from child activity

Tags: android, android-layout

All,

I have an *ActivityGroup*, incorporated with a *activity* (with the help of *LocalActivityManager*) of other application.

Is there any hook, such that child *Activity* should be able to invoke methods of *ActivityGroup*?

Regards,
Muks Dev

Comment: Are you talking about some other application using your Activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity.getParent()
```

Is this what your are  looking for?

Answer (score 0):

try `getParent()` and cast it to the class of your `ActivityGroup`